When creating basic pywebview application on RASPI, frameless=True does not remove the frame from the window but running same program on windows does
I am running a basic webview application on a raspberry pi that when running frameless=True it is not making the window frameless like it should and the same code is working fine on windows machine. Pywebview is running version 5.0.5.
When editing the frameless between false and true it does adjust the screen size but does not result in a frameless window.

Right click on the top border and choose undecorate. It should fix the problem
(source: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=214779)
